# calculate the angle between a line and x-axis

Tags: swift, math, sprite-kit, trigonometry

I have two points in my coordinate system `(x,y)` that I want to know the angle of their line and x-axis.

I use swift for solving this but I can't get the angle.

I need this angle in radians to use it in the following equation:

```
(x0 + r cos theta, y0 + r sin theta)
```

r : radius of circle

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have two points, `(x0, y0)` and `(x1, y1)`, then the angle of the line joining them (relative to the X axis) is given by:

```
theta = atan2((y1 - y0), (x1 - x0))
```

Answer (score 1):

The angle between a line, for reference, let's call this A,  defined by two points p1=(x1,y1),p2=(x2, y2) and the x-axis is related to finding the slope/ gradient of the line, A.

```
# To solve a problem you sometimes have to simplify it and then work up to the full solution"
```

Let's start by obtaining the gradient of the line A.

The gradient of line A:

```
slope = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)
```

for a straight line, that makes an angle theta with the x-axis
tan(theta) = slope = (change in y) / (change in x)

Therefore, theta = tan_inverse (slope)

```
theta = atan(slope)
```