# Swift UIView pointing by rotating at another UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

[image]

I have a small app that I am working on and it contains this piece of UI.

The user can touch and move the speaker, which is now located in the center. Based on that some other values in the rest of the UI changes, it ranges from -10 to 10 and has 2 angels, a X and a Y.

Based on where the speaker is I need to point the soundwaves to the speakers (in all the corners). How do I do that? Can I manipulate X and Y so I can do it with:

```
extension UIView{
    func rotate(angle: CGFloat) {
        let radians = angle / 180.0 * CGFloat(Double.pi)
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: radians)
    }
}
```

or is there any other simpler method to di this? I got the `touchesMoved` already fixed and it doesn't move out of the image so that is working ok. The X and Y coordinates are also done.

I now only need to move these soundwaves which are simple `UIImage`s. It would be ideal if they would stretch and shrink too based on how far the speaker is.

Comment: Are you using a Storyboard or Nib for the view or is it all via code?

Comment: That's more a maths problem: How to get angle between two points (with in a "basic horizontal line"). See there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855261/calculate-the-angle-between-a-line-and-x-axis

Comment: @StePrescott well, xib but the animation must be done through code, I suppose.